# Show only dates bigger than the search pattern even if the search pattern does not exist in the (log) file

Tags: sed, grep, logs, date, time

I want to search the syslog for dates bigger than a specific search pattern. For example I want to find every syslog entry where the date is bigger than `JAN  6 16:24:00`. I know I could use sed (`sed -n '/JAN  6 16:24:00/,$p' ${LOGFILE}`) but this will only work if an entry with the exact date that I specified in `sed` exists - if there's no entry in the logfile containing exactly `JAN  6 16:24:00`, I will get no output since there's no real logic, only strings are being compared.

I know about `journalctl --since "XXX"` but this may run on a host that's not based on SystemD, but basically I need quite this functionality.

Is there a way to print all entries in a logfile that are newer than the date `X` supposed that the logfile does not contain `X` using "classic" GNU tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your logs were formatted in a more useful format like:

```
2021-01-06 16:24:00 log text
```

You could do:

```
awk '$0 >= "2021-01-06 16:24:00"'
```

But here, it's more complicated as those dates are formatted using English month name abbreviations and the year is not even specified.

Best would be to use a date parser that can understand that timestamp format and understand year-less timestamps as being one from the latest occurrence in the past, like the `Date::Parse` perl module:

```
<yourfile.log perl -MDate::Parse -ne '
  BEGIN{$start = str2time("2021-01-06 16:24")}
  print if str2time(substr($_, 0, 15)) >= $start'
```

For year-less dates, `Date::Parse`'s `str2time` appears to give dates in the past except if the date is from the current month. For instance, if run on Jan 15 2022, "Feb 2" would be interpreted as 2021-02-02, while "Jan 31" would be interpreted as 2022-01-31.

Comment: Using `awk '$0 >= "2021-01-06 16:24:00"'` is an excellent solution after converting the datetime format.